# How to change the back color of particular row in datagridview c#.net?

Tags: datagridview, row, backcolor

I have task,in my datagridview if i delete one row, that row will change the back color not delete in database until operations(update or save) commited. How can do this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to provide a complete answer due to lack of information and code in your question. You might need something like this.

```
private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
}
```

Follow these links. I think they maybe useful for you to solve your issue.

[`UserDeletingRow` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow.aspx) (fires when a row is about to get deleted)

[`DefaultCellStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle.aspx) (to change the BackColor of the CurrentRow)